# how to do sortable in ionic3 / angular4

Tags: angular, ionic3

I need to make ion-card sortable in ionic3. I am using jquery sortable plugin, in web env, it worked fine, but in ionic3, it is not working.

```
<div class="container">
        <div *ngFor="let tab of page.tabs" class="tab"
            [ngClass]="{'selected': tab==page.currentTab}"
            (click)="this.choose($event, tab)">

            <ion-card>
                <ion-card-header> 
                 {{tab.get('title')}} 
                </ion-card-header> 
                <ion-card-content> 
                    <count-items [item_counts]="tab.countItems"></count-items>
                </ion-card-content> 
            </ion-card>
        </div>
```

And in view:

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.pageService.generateCountSummaryForTabs();
        var _parent = this;
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('starting...');
            console.log(  this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName( 'container' )[0] )
            jQuery( this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName( 'container' )[0] ).sortable( {
                handle: ".handle",
                startPos: null,
                endPos: null,
                start: function( event, ui ) {
                    this.startPos = ui.item.index();
                },
                stop: function( event, ui ) {
                    this.endPos = ui.item.index();
                    //1. update the dataTableObject orderedList position
                    _parent.pageService.swapTab( this.startPos, this.endPos );
                }
            });
        }, 500 );
    }
```

But when I load the page, the card is NOT sortable at all, and I am not seeing error from console at all.

Can anyone tell me how to make card sortable in ionic3?

Comment: The better way to approach this problems is I have data, I have a view, I want my view to reflect the data.  So to "sort your cards" is really to just sort your array of data.  The view only be concerned with the array in question,  You controller logic will only be concerned with modifying the data if that makes any sense.  Don't sort the ion-cards..just your data.

Comment: Of course you need to sort data, but what I need is sorting effect. I need the card to be draggable or sortable, then when user changes its position, the backend data also changed position. Right now, Sortable is not working in ionic3

Answer (score 2):

**component.html (Template file)**

```
<div class="container">
  <ion-list (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)" reorder="true">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let tab of page.tabs" class="tab">
        <ion-card>
            <ion-card-header>
              {{tab.get('title')}}
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content>
              <count-items [item_counts]="tab.countItems"></count-items>
            </ion-card-content>
          </ion-card>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
reorderItems(indexes) {
    let element = this.chats[indexes.from];
    this.chats.splice(indexes.from, 1);
    this.chats.splice(indexes.to, 0, element);
}
```

Refer [Ionic Item Reorder](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemReorder/) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

**Try [ItemReorder](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemReorder/) from Ionic API**

> Item reorder adds the ability to change an item's order in a group. It
>   can be used within an ion-list or ion-item-group to provide a visual
>   drag and drop interface.

**Template**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header>Header</ion-list-header>
  <ion-item-group reorder="true" (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event)">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-card>
        // your code here
      </ion-card>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
</ion-list>
```

**Controller**

```
let items = [1,2,3,4,5];

reorderItems(indexes) {
    let element = this.items[indexes.from];
    this.items.splice(indexes.from, 1);
    this.items.splice(indexes.to, 0, element);
}
```